# Cannot get BibTex to work

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, texmaker

I'm new to LaTeX. I have been searching for hours and tried multiple solutions that appear to solve the problem but all it does is it comes up with a different error.

I'm using TexMaker to try and make a template for my thesis. So when it came to downloading the BibTeX I followed the procedure as on most online tutorials. But then I get this error.

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) MainBody.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Citation Undefined (in another chapter)

I have ensured the correct options were chosen in the configuration.
[image]

[image]

If I change `bibtex %` to `biber %` in the configuration menu then I receive the following error:

INFO - This is Biber 2.16 INFO - Logfile is 'MainBody.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find 'MainBody.bcf'! INFO - ERRORS: 1

I have attached a template of my document.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper,
             top=25.4 mm,
             bottom=25.4 mm}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

    
\title{x}
\author{x}
\date{x}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and my Introduction.tex is as follows:

```
\section{1}
Ref check: \parencite{KHAN2019908}
```

my References.bib is as follows:

```
@article{KHAN2019908,
title = {Nanoparticles: Properties, applications and toxicities},
journal = {Arabian Journal of Chemistry},
volume = {12},
number = {7},
pages = {908-931},
year = {2019},
issn = {1878-5352},
author = {Ibrahim Khan and Khalid Saeed and Idrees Khan}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Make the change to `biber %` as you wrote in your second part, and then remove the check at "use a build subdirectory" and try again.

Comment: If I do that then I receive the same error: LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references. Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) MainBody. LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references. Citation Undefined (in another chapter)

Comment: don't test on your whole document. Try first with the small example. If you know that one reference works, you can try to figure out what is wrong in your real document.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to work in the example. I then noticed that my whole document did not have the right directory for reference.bib.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it turned out that the problem was caused by using the wrong file path in the `\addbibresource` call. This has been resolved and things appear to work. See comment above.